# Mongodb UseUnifiedTopology: True causes connection errors in my code

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a small app written in Node.js that downloads some data from an API, and then saves it into a MongoDB.  When I have `useunifiedtopology: false` my code runs fine, connects to the mongodb fine and updates everything fine.

When I set `useunifiedtopolgy: true` I get the following errors

> MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended

Here is what I am trying to accomplish...I can't for the life of me figure out where it's going wrong.  If I remove the db.close() from dbupdater.js, it works, but the app just hangs.

Here is how I am going about things...

It should also be noted, that if I remove the multiple locations and extraction calls from below, then it does work fine.  The errors noted above when using `useunifiedtopology: false` only seem to happen when I am doing multiple calls to the dbupdater module.  So, to be clear, if I just hit the API once, and do one call to dbupdater, it works fine.  If I call the API and the dbupdater function multiple times, it fails with the error:

> MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended.

app.js Contents:

```
const Downloader = require('./modules/Downloader')
const dbupdater = require('./modules/dbUpdater')

var Locations = ['Location1','Location2']
var ExtractionTypes = ['Extraction1','Extraction2','Extraction3' ]


var interval = 60000;   //API Request Delay in MS
var promise = Promise.resolve();

function main() {

    Locations.forEach(location => {
        promise = promise.then(function(){          

            ExtractionTypes.forEach(extraction =>{

                promise = promise.then(function(){          

                    talonDownloader(location,extraction,function(data){

                        if (data == null) {
                            console.log(`No ${extraction} Data Recieved for period requested.`)
                        } 
                        else {
                            dbupdater(extraction,data)
                        }
                    })

                    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                        setTimeout(resolve, interval)
                    })    
                })
            })
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                setTimeout(resolve, interval)
            })    
        })
    })
}
main();
```

Then here is the code for my dbupdater...

dbudater.js

```
module.exports = function (extraction,data) {
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const date = require('date-and-time');   
    const crypto = require('crypto')
    const dburl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
    const dbName = 'palDB'


    //Initialize Date Information
    const now = new Date()
    const todayDate = date.format(now, 'DD-MMM-YYYY')


    if (extraction == 'operation') {
        var collectionName = 'operations'
        var indexValue = 'ACTIVITY_ID'
        updateDBGeneral();
    }
    else if (extraction == 'aircraft') {
        var collectionName = 'aircraft'
        var indexValue = 'AIRCRAFT_ID'
        updateDBGeneral();
        updateDBHistorical();
    }
    else if (extraction == 'cancelanalysis') {
        var collectionName = 'cancelAnalysis'
        var indexValue = 'SCH_ACT_ID'
        updateDBGeneral();  
    }
    else if (extraction == 'dailyflylog') {
        var collectionName = 'dfl'
        var indexValue = 'SCH_ACT_ID'
        updateDBGeneral();  
    }
    else if (extraction == 'instructor') {
        var collectionName = 'instructor'
        var indexValue = 'ETA_ID'
        updateDBGeneral();  
    }
    else if (extraction == 'resschedproductivity') {
        var collectionName = 'resSchedProductivity'
        var indexValue = 'opid'
        updateDBGeneral();    
    }
    else if (extraction == 'student') {
        var collectionName = 'student'
        var indexValue = 'ETA_ID'
        updateDBGeneral();  
    }
    else if (extraction == 'trainingrecord') {
        var collectionName = 'trgrec'
        var indexValue = 'STUDENT_REGISTRATION_ID'
        updateDBGeneral();   
    }
    else if (extraction == 'studentprogression') {
        var collectionName = 'studentProgression'
        var indexValue = 'studentProgIndex'
        updateDBGeneral();   
    }

    //Initialize DB Updater functions
    function updateDBGeneral(){


        MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
        .then((db) => {
            var dbo = db.db(dbName);
            console.log(`Connection Established to ${dbo.databaseName} database.`)
            data.forEach(element => {    


                if (indexValue == 'opid') {          

                    element[indexValue] = crypto.createHash('md5').update(element.CAL_DATE + element.RES_TYPE_ID).digest('hex'); //Add Value to filter on
                    var filter = {[indexValue]: element[indexValue]};

                } else if (indexValue =='studentProgIndex'){

                    element[indexValue] = crypto.createHash('md5').update(element.PERS_REGISTER_ID + element.UNIT + element.ACT_START).digest('hex'); //Add value to filter on 
                    var filter = {[indexValue]: element[indexValue]}   

                } else var filter = {[indexValue]: element[indexValue]}

                dbo.collection(collectionName)
                    .updateOne(filter, {$set:element},{upsert:true})
                    .then( result => db.close())
                    .catch( err => console.log(err));
            })
        })
        .catch( err => console.log(err));
    }     

    function updateDBHistorical(){


    }
}
```

Comment: I do not get that error (https://github.com/p-mongo/tests/blob/master/node-session/test.js). If you have more code in your application, try to reduce the failing case further.

Comment: @oleg I updated my post with some further information, after taking your recommendation.

Comment: Are you using the current version of node driver?

Comment: As far as I know...v3.5.6

Comment: I would suggest working through the control flow in your program to eliminate the possibility of an operation being constructed in an overlapping fashion, where you expect to construct it e.g. after some data is retrieved, but it is partially constructed before the retrieval starts. This or reduce your example to the node driver only, basically creating a single .js file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I will take a stab at what you suggest....Curious that it works fine if useunifiedtopology: false is set....

Comment: Tore everything down, and built it all back up, and now it is working.  Thanks.